# Control to send which attributes accoring to error presenence or not from Serialzer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I 'm working on an API in rails.

I just want that, at time to create an object through API if object created successfully than return all fields of abject except error in json form through serializer and if an error comes that return only error field and don't send other fields.
I 'm doing this

```
attributes :id,:errors,:member_id,:course_id,:event_id,:seating_id,:da,:people,:notes
  def errors
    object.errors.full_messages
  end
```

But it give all empty fields with actual error if error exist,
Surely, its behaving same way as I have written it.

But how can I make it to return only error if error exist

Comment: If I understand right, you are using a create block to create objects. If the object was successfully created you wish to return the object and it's attributes. But if an error occurs you wish to return the error message.

Comment: @SoumojitGhosh exactly

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are having a create method for example, obj.create(obj_params)

Align your code to something like this,

```
@result = {}
@obj = User.create(user_params)
if @obj.errors.full_messages.count > 0
    //return the array of errors
    @result = @obj.errors.full_messages
else
    //return the object created
    @result = @obj
end
render json: @result
```

The idea here is that if there was an error while object creation the array of errors.full_messages will not be empty. Hence we are placing a check on the number of elements in the array using count.

Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Cheers!

Comment: This is simple but the main point is to control it from Serializer, and you completely ignored it

Comment: How exactly are you using your Serializer? Can you please provide a snippet of code. Are you using obj.as_json or something like that?

Comment: I have already attached code from my serialzier. we write this in api defaults "formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers" which means
 when we return any object (new created object in this case), it goes to find the serialzer with the object's name like event_seralizer if it founds it than return fields defined like "attributes :id, :errors" in event_serializer, otherwise return whole object